# How to pass a tuple of multiple returned values from a function_1 to function_2, in a single call of function_1 in function_2

Tags: python-3.x, function, tuples, return, simulation

I have a function_1 as this:

```
def my_func_1():
    a = 2
    b = 3

    r1 = a+b
    r2 = a*b

    return r1, r2
```

I want to call this function_1 in another function_2. The issue is I can call the function_1 returned values as this in function_2:

```
import my_func_1 *

def my_func_2():
    result_1 = my_func_1()[0]
    result_2 = my_func_1()[1]
```

The issue is `my_func_1()` is reasonably  computational heavy. I should be able to call the function_1 once while assigning the different returned values to different variables in function_2. How may I do this. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: `result_1, result_2 = my_func_1()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh, this is so easy, I got it:

```
import my_func_1 *

def my_func_2():
    result = my_func_1()
    result_1 = result[0]
    result_2 = result[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of returning r1 and r2, declare r1 and r2 as global variables in my_func_1(). Not just r1 and r2, If you also want to declare more variables executed by my_func_1(), you can declare. Let my_func_1() not return anything. Execute my_func_1(). And then use r1 and r2 in my_func_2().

```
def my_func_1():
    global r1
    global r2
    a = 2
    b = 3
    r1 = a+b
    r2 = a*b
    #do not return any value


'''
this step is important since global variables r1 & r2 can be used by
other functions only if my_func_1() is executed
'''

my_func_1()


def my_func_2():

    #Do whatever you want to do with r1 & r2
    result_1 = r1
    result_2 = r2
```

Comment: Declaring variables as global in my function can be counterintuitive, as my actual script is complex and I am reusing a lot of variable names. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Sayantan4796, If you can provide  a part of the code, I'll try to split up in such a way to  be less complex resulting in lesser executing time.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your zeal for helping out. But I shall pass on that.